# libvips in C++ on Mac

Tags: c++, macos, cmake, clion, vips

I trying to write a program in CLion IDE that read a pdf file with C++ vips library and I get this error. What it's wrong?

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "vips::VImage::pdfload(char const*, vips::VOption*)", referenced from:
      _main in main.cpp.o
  "vips::VImage::write_to_file(char const*, vips::VOption*) const", referenced from:
      _main in main.cpp.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

**My OS:** Mac OS Monteray

**My Code**

```
#include <vips/vips8>

using namespace vips;
using namespace std;

int main() {

    VImage in =  VImage().pdfload("/Users/myuser/CLionProjects/untitled3/files/doc.pdf");
    in.write_to_file("/Users/myuser/CLionProjects/untitled3/output/img.jpeg");

}
```

**CMakeList.txt**

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.19)
project(untitled5)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 11)

find_package(PkgConfig REQUIRED)
pkg_search_module(GLIB REQUIRED glib-2.0)
pkg_search_module(VIPS REQUIRED vips)

include_directories(${GLIB_INCLUDE_DIRS})
link_directories(${GLIB_LIBRARY_DIRS})
include_directories(${VIPS_INCLUDE_DIRS})
link_directories(${VIPS_LIBRARY_DIRS})

add_executable(untitled5 main.cpp)

add_definitions(${GLIB_CFLAGS_OTHER})
target_link_libraries(untitled5 ${GLIB_LIBRARIES})
target_link_libraries(untitled5 ${VIPS_LIBRARIES})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The missing libraries libvips-cpp to link to.

```bash
# pkg_search_module(VIPS REQUIRED vips)
pkg_search_module(VIPS REQUIRED vips-cpp)
```

`pkg_search_module(GLIB REQUIRED glib-2.0)` can be removed, vips-cpp provides it in the libs

```bash
$ pkg-config --libs vips-cpp
-L/usr/local/lib -lvips-cpp -lvips -lgobject-2.0 -lglib-2.0
```

Comment: Oh i see! Thanks, works here